# Removing one of the many duplicate entries in a habtm relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

For the purposes of the discussion I cooked up a test with two tables:

```
:stones and :bowls (both created with just timestamps - trivial)

create_table :bowls_stones, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :bowl_id,  :null => false
  t.integer :stone_id, :null => false
end
```

The models are pretty self-explanatory, and basic, but here they are:

```
class Stone < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :bowls

end

class Bowl < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :stones

end
```

Now, the issue is: I want there to be many of the same stone in each bowl. And I want to be able to remove only one, leaving the other identical stones behind. This seems pretty basic, and I'm really hoping that I can both find a solution and not feel like too much of an idiot when I do.

Here's a test run:

```
@stone = Stone.new
@stone.save
@bowl = Bowl.new
@bowl.save

#test1 - .delete
5.times do
  @bowl.stones << @stone
end

@bowl.stones.count
=> 5
@bowl.stones.delete(@stone)
@bowl.stones.count
=> 0
#removed them all!

#test2 - .delete_at
5.times do
  @bowl.stones << @stone
end

@bowl.stones.count
=> 5
index = @bowl.stones.index(@stone)
@bowl.stones.delete_at(index)
@bowl.stones.count
=> 5
#not surprising, I guess... delete_at isn't part of habtm. Fails silently, though.
@bowl.stones.clear

#this is ridiculous, but... let's wipe it all out
5.times do
  @bowl.stones << @stone
end

@bowl.stones.count
=> 5
ids = @bowl.stone_ids
index = ids.index(@stone.id)
ids.delete_at(index)
@bowl.stones.clear
ids.each do |id|
  @bowl.stones << Stone.find(id)
end
@bowl.stones.count
=> 4
#Is this really the only way?
```

So... is blowing away the whole thing and reconstructing it from keys really the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a `has_many :through` relationship here.  Otherwise, yes, the only way to accomplish your goal is to create a method to count the current number of a particular stone, delete them all, then add `N - 1` stones back.

```
class Bowl << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stones

  def remove_stone(stone, count = 1)
    current_stones = self.stones.find(:all, :conditions => {:stone_id => stone.id})
    self.stones.delete(stone)
    (current_stones.size - count).times { self.stones << stone }
  end
end
```

Remember that `LIMIT` clauses are not supported in `DELETE` statements so there really is no way to accomplish what you want in SQL without some sort of other identifier in your table.

(MySQL actually does support `DELETE ... LIMIT 1` but AFAIK ActiveRecord won't do that for you.  You'd need to execute raw SQL.)

Comment: I'm convinced! I did not know that LIMIT was not supported by DELETE (and hadn't gotten desperately curious enough to dig in the SQL lorebooks yet). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the relationship have to be `habtm`?

You could have something like this ...

```
class Stone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stone_placements
end

class StonePlacement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bowl
  belongs_to :stone
end

class Bowl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stone_placements
  has_many :stones, :through => :stone_placements

  def contents
    self.stone_placements.collect{|p| [p.stone] * p.count }.flatten
  end

  def contents= contents
    contents.sort!{|a, b| a.id <=> b.id}
    contents.uniq.each{|stone|
      count = (contents.rindex(stone) - contents.index(stone)) + 1
      if self.stones.include?(stone)
        placement = self.stone_placements.find(:first, :conditions => ["stone_id = ?", stone])
        if contents.include?(stone)
          placement.count = count
          placement.save!
        else
          placement.destroy!
        end
      else
        self.stone_placements << StonePlacement.create(:stone => stone, :bowl => self, :count => count)
      end
    }
  end
end
```

... assuming you have a `count` field on `StonePlacement` to increment and decrement.

Comment: Well, no... I suppose it doesn't HAVE to be. I've certainly considered your workaround... ultimately, I'd rather move around actual objects than keep counters. Love your pic.

Comment: You could also do `StonePlacement.find_by_bowl_and_stone(@bowl, @stone).first.destroy` or something similar if you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Sure sure... having an intermediate object to manipulate opens up all kinds of possibilities. Is the answer to my question, then, a "no?"

Comment: I don't think that working hard to have multiple identical rows (i.e. impossible to know which one you're going to operate on) in the join table is a good use of your time. If you want to add and remove stones from bowls, there's nothing stopping you from adding an add_stone or remove_stone method to your bowl object.

Comment: Updated answer to fake out what I think you're after.

Comment: It's clear that you're right - having an intermediate table is clearly the way to go.

It really seems like there must be a way to do what I was originally trying to do, however.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
bowl.stones.slice!(0)
```

Comment: >> @bowl.stones.count
=> 5
>> @bowl.stones.slice!(0)
=> #<Stone id: 2, created_at: "2009-07-08 13:41:06", updated_at: "2009-07-08 13:41:06">
>> @bowl.stones.count
=> 5
# slice isn't a habtm method, but I did get my hopes up a bit.

Comment: Ahh, sorry.  Worth a shot, though.